# write to file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

I am a python beginner.
I am writing to a file as:

```
   with open("Init", mode='w') as out:
     out.write(datName)
     out.write("\n")
     out.write("T\n")
     out.write(datGroup)
     out.write("\n")
     out.write(datLatx) 
     out.write("  ")
```

while this is working, it is looking bad (space and newline is separate write statement).

I read this [page](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), but still no idea.

Is there a better way of doing this given `out.write(datName"\n")` is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do

```
out.write(datName + "\n")
```

but it may be easier to just use `print`:

```
print(datName, file=out)
```

as `print` automatically appends a newline.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output of many print statements to be redirected to a file, you could use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) in Python 3.4+, for older Python versions see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('init.txt', 'w') as file, redirect_stdout(file):
    print(datName)
    print("T")
    print(datGroup)
    print(datLatx, end="  ")
```

You could also combine the print statements:

```
with open('init.txt', 'w') as file:
    print("\n".join([datName, "T", datGroup, datLatx]),
          end="  ", file=file)
```